# Data recovery of 5.25" floppy disks using bootable GNU/Linux distros?

Tags: linux, data-recovery

When attempting to recover data from old floppy disks (5.25" in this case), it may contain a lot of bad sectors and have other issues. Tools such as [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) make it more likely to be able to recover more data than simply copying files in DOS.

My question is, what is the ideal bootable (CD) GNU/Linux distro that can be used with a very old computer and also comes pre-installed with data recovery tools, especially tools (if any) designed for floppy disk data recovery (although a minimum should be basic console tools and ddrescue)? If having access to a system that can boot from a CD, but still has a 5.25" floppy disk drive mounted in it, then such a system could boot a lot of relatively modern media. However, a lot of distros even for 32-bit seem to require PAE. In this particular case the system is Pentium 1 based.

Simply by trial and error I could probably find a distro designed for old computers that has some basic recovery tools, but it would be very nice for myself and possibly others in a similar situation with advice or a list (not an exhaustive one) of alternatives. I assume few distros are made for old computers **and** for data recovery, which hopefully doesn't make this question too broad.

Comment: I believe you're trying distros that are too user friendly :).  Well established distros: `arch`, `debian` or even `knoppix` shall boot without PAE.  I strongly recommend [`knoppix`](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) for recovery, the distro aims to be used as a recovery live CD.

Comment: Note: Pentiums are OK with Debian, but support for 386 was dropped from sarge (3.1) and for 486 from squeeze (6.0).  https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch02s01.html.en - btw, you might want to try **old** versions of [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) or [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: I'll just add a comment, as my suggestion doesn't conform with the title ("bootable GNU/Linux distros"): I've had amazing results with Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier. It literally saved my life once or twice. It is compatible with floppy disks. If you are able to install (or already have) a Windows 9x on said system, I think that may cut down your work. Linky: http://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29 (scroll at the bottom of the list). Caveat: I used only the "Win 2000 and up" version.

Comment: There are very few distros that support anything older than the Pentium Pro (commonly described as "i686").  For an original-flavor Pentium, your best bet is probably to roll your own using i486 Gentoo as the starting point.